# how to show calculated amount in textbox on form load event from datagridview which has passed to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using one textbox and datagridview .In which i have made calculation (total amount)using gridview cells,and total amount of entire cell is display in textbox.But it is showing only in edit mode.I want the total value also displayed on form loading time.

```
private void datagrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     double value1 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
     double value2 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
     double value3 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
     double value4 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
     datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = ((value2 + (value3/100)) * value1) - (value4/100);

     if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
     {
        summition();
     }
}
void summition()
{
     double sum = 0;
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
     {
         if (!row.IsNewRow)
             sum += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
     }    
     texttotal.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your code into seperate function`(CalculateSum)` and call this function when Form is Loaded and DataGridCell is changed.

so you need to hadnle Form_Load event additionally to call the `(CalculateSum)` function.

Subscribe to the Form_Load event as below:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

**Complete Code**

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
private void datagrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    CalculateSum();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateSum();
}
private void CalculateSum()
{
    double value1 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
    double value2 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
    double value3 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
    double value4 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
    datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = ((value2 + (value3/100)) * value1) - (value4/100);

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        summition();
    }
}
```

Comment: where i have to write this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);

Comment: you can generate the Form_Load event handler by just double clicking the Form, or you can just add it in just in your Form Class

Comment: its showing error "object reference not set to an instance of object"

Comment: @user3467599: where are you getting the exception? can you update your question with latest code?

Answer (score 0):

**Two alternatives:**

1. You can call the function `datagrid_CellEndEdit` itself from the `Form_Load` event. Something like:

   ```
   this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
   MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       datagrid_CellEndEdit(null,null)
   }
   ```
2. You can create another method which will be invoked from both `Form_Load` event and `datagrid_CellEndEdit` event.

   Eg:

   ```
   this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
   private void datagrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       Calculate();
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Calculate();
   }

   private void Calculate()
   {
       double value1 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
       double value2 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
       double value3 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
       double value4 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
       datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = ((value2 + (value3/100)) * value1) - (value4/100);

       if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
       {
           summition();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: its showing error "object reference not set to an instance of object"

Comment: @user3467599: Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: "null reference exception was unhandled by user" at here  'double value1 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
    '

Comment: @user3467599: That is because `datagrid` is not initialized before running this code.

Comment: how can i initialize ,please tell me sir

Comment: @user3467599: Show some more code. Where do you bind data to the datagridview?

Comment: i have updated the code with adding datagridview binding code

Comment: @user3467599: Make sure `initializeComponent()` is executed in the class constructor before control flow reaches `calculate()` or `datagrid_CellEndEdit()`.

Comment: @user3467599: Did you check `initializeComponent()` is being executed before `calculate()`?

Comment: i am getting error in calculate method" 'e' does not exists in current context"